# How to update git submodule to a specific commit?

Tags: git, git-submodules

```
git submodule update --remote
```

Above command updates the submodule to latest commit however I want to update to a specific commit (e.g. to some commit hash). How to achieve that ?

Comment: `cd submodule; git checkout <some_commit_hash>` (and don't forget to commit the change in the parent repository)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`git` submodules are repositories inside a repository, hence it has the same behavior as any other `git` repository. Hence enter the dependency root by using `cd submodule` and use any git command.

```
cd submodule
git checkout -b NEW_BRANCH_NAME COMMIT_ID
```