# Find git commit where a particular submodule commit was introduced

Tags: git

My question relates to git repo archaeology as opposed to [checking out submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70988396/how-to-update-git-submodule-to-a-specific-commit) or [committing submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914022/how-do-i-check-out-a-specific-version-of-a-submodule-using-git-submodule).

**Desired Solution**

Suppose I have a repo FOO with a submodule BAR that has this history

```
Submodule (BAR) commit history (latest commit first)

o - commit E
|
o - commit D
|
o - commit C
|
o - commit B
|
o - commit A


Main repo (FOO) history of submodule commits (latest commit first)

o - commit 3: update submodule to commit E
|
o - commit 2: update submodule to commit C
|
o - commit 1: update submodule to commit A
```

I would like a command to reveal when the changes made in `commit B` were present in the the main FOO repo. The command would return `commit 2` since `commit B` was not present in the submodule in `commit 1` but it was present in the submodule in `commit 2`.

**Current Workaround**

```
cd foo
git log -p bar
```

Then record BAR commit hashes used in commit 1, 2, and 3

```
cd bar
git log
```

Then find `commit B` and scroll up and down to discover where `commit B` lies relative to the commit hashes I recorded. Only then would I know that `commit B` was introduced into the main repo in `commit 2`.

EDIT:

```
git submodule summary
```

is useful but doesn't quite ring the bell. At least in my version of `git`, it reports merges in the submodule but doesn't list the commit hashes except the starting and ending hash (which are also available in the above `git log -p` command used in the workaround).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git log --raw --format='%h' path/to/submodule` will show you the commit id each time the submodule is updated. E.g., using the [micropython](https://github.com/micropython/micropython) repository, running `git log -q --raw lib/axtls` shows:

```
$ git log --raw --format='%h' lib/axtls
75c1609c3

:160000 160000 43a6e6bd3 531cab9c2 M    lib/axtls
99bf5448b

:160000 160000 dac9176ca 43a6e6bd3 M    lib/axtls
8f9af63c2

:160000 160000 9b3092eb3 dac9176ca M    lib/axtls
f01c1c6b3

:160000 160000 67d27df4b 9b3092eb3 M    lib/axtls
26d5e91bf

:160000 160000 9776795d9 67d27df4b M    lib/axtls
7711d8756

:160000 160000 c2690dc10 9776795d9 M    lib/axtls
1f0dfe37a

:160000 160000 532d2302b c2690dc10 M    lib/axtls
5e919b7ef

:160000 160000 5773c1446 532d2302b M    lib/axtls
f4d55c91f

:160000 160000 a39ebe4d7 5773c1446 M    lib/axtls
90a36942b

:000000 160000 000000000 a39ebe4d7 A    lib/axtls
```

From that, for instance, I know that `lib/axtls` commit `9b3092eb3` was introduced in `micropython` commit `f01c1c6b3`.

Comment: My question is focused on identifying a submodule commit that was made between two submodule commits that were committed to the main repo. For example, what if I am trying to find a commit that was made between 67d27df4b and 9b3092eb3? Is there a way to that without first doing as you suggest and then digging into the submodule repo?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're asking about; I think this correctly answers, "Find git commit where a particular submodule commit was introduced". If you're trying to find some intermediate submodule commit, you could automate the above and then use `git merge-base --is-ancestor` to figure out if that commit introduced a particular submodule commit.

Comment: Yes -- I am asking about an intermediate commit (in my post, I called it commit B). Your hint about using `merge-base` is useful. I was hoping not to have to write a script. Is there no command that does this automatically?

Comment: I don't believe there is any built-in mechanism to do this.